# Send Responses request through visual studio 2013

Tags: json, visual-studio-2013

Currently, i am using visual studio 2013 as Azure load and performance testing. Now i need to use Azure performance testing of sending a set of Jason request. So that i can test the time in which my responses persist in db. How can it be done? Also i am sending this Jason with a validation token. I have achieved this testing with j-meter but have no idea with VS. I can attach j-meter file what i am doing.Kindly assist me on this so that later on i can parameter my Jason with multiple requests.